# Julia - C interface with nonfundamental types

Tags: c, julia

I am extending a Julia package that uses a C library.  I need to call some C functions from Julia.  They look something like this:

```
struct contained {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
struct mystruct {
    int n;
    contained* arr;
};
mystruct* mk_mystruct(int n, contained* arr);
void use_mystruct(mystruct* foo);
```

I have also declared the corresponding types in Julia:

```
type contained
    x::Int64
    y::Int64
    z::Int64
end
type mystruct
    n::Int64
    arr::Array{contained, 1}
end
```

To `ccall` functions which take a `contained*` as an argument, everything works fine treating the `contained*` as `Ptr{Int64}`:

```
con = fill(0, 5, 3);
mys = ccall((:mk_mystruct, "mylib"), Ptr{mystruct}, (Int64, Ptr{Int64}), n, con)
```

I suppose this works because `contained` has the same memory layout as an array of Int64s.  This is also how it is done elsewhere in the Julia package.  But the only way I know to check the value of the returned `mystruct` is to dereference it with `unsafe_load`, at which point Julia crashes from a segfault.  What is the right way to dereference a pointer in Julia?

The C library also includes pretty-printing functions, so instead of dereferencing the pointer in Julia I could treat the pointer as opaque and pass it back to this C function:

```
void print_mystruct(mystruct* foo, FILE* outputfile)
```

In the C code, this is called with `outputfile=stdout`.  How would I set this up with `ccall`?  This obviously does not work:

```
ccall((:print_mystruct, "mylib"), Void, (Ptr{mystruct}, Ptr{Void}), mys, stdout)
```

What should I put instead of `Ptr{Void}` and `stdout`?  How does Julia implement I/O in the C interface?

Comment: Why use `Int64` as a corresponding type to C's `int`?  `int` is commonly 32- bit, maybe as narrow as 16-bits and can be many other larger sizes.

Comment: Actually I used `Int`, but since `Int` means `Int64` on my machine I put `Int64` in the above code so there would be no confusion.  My understanding is that Julia detects the appropriate size of `Int`, so that on this machine C's `int` is also 64 bits.  Is that correct?

Comment: The size of an `int` in C is controlled by the compiler and options, not the processor.  Both 32-bit and 64-bit `int` are found with compilers for 64-bit machines for various reasons.

Comment: The right kind of int to use is `Cint`, which will resolve to the size of an `int` in C, which is not necessarily the same as the word size of the machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare the type in Julia, you must declare the same types as C:

```
type contained
    x::Cint
    y::Cint
    z::Cint
end
type mystruct
    n::Cint
    arr::Ptr{contained}
end
```

The Julia type `Array{contained, 1}` would correspond to `jl_value_t*` in C and the Julia type `Int` would correspond to `intptr_t` in C.

I don't know of a platform-agnostic way to get a handle to `stdout`, as most platforms require expanding a C header macro to find out the real symbol name. For example, on macOS, it gets renamed to `__stdoutp`:

```
julia> unsafe_load(cglobal(:__stdoutp, Ptr{Void}))
Ptr{Void} @0x00007fff751f7348

julia> ccall(:fprintf, Csize_t, (Ptr{Void}, Cstring, Cint...), ans, "hi\n")
hi
0x0000000000000003
```

You may be interested in checking out the [Clang.jl package](https://github.com/ihnorton/Clang.jl) which can automatically generate these definitions from parsing the header files.

Comment: Ok, I replaced `Int64` with `Cint` everywhere, and changed `Array{contained,1}` to `Ptr{contained}`.  Now I want to verify that `mk_mystruct` did the right thing, so I define `Base.show(m::mystruct)`.  How can I do this with a `Ptr{contained}` rather than an `Array{contained,1}`?  Is there any relationship between pointers and arrays in Julia?

Comment: @MatthewBedford look into `unsafe_wrap`