# Julia - C types with struct hack cause segfault

Tags: c, struct, julia

This question is a followup to [Julia - C interface with nonfundamental types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729347/julia-c-interface-with-nonfundamental-types), with enough new information to be considered a different question.  I use a C library that has two types like this, with three possible versions of `mystruct`:

```
struct contained {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
struct mystruct {
    int n;
//original:
//    contained* arr;
//struct hack version 1:
//    contained arr[1];
//struct hack version 2:
      contained arr[];
};
```

Using the answer from the original question, I have defined the following corresponding Julia types, which work fine with the original version of `mystruct`, but not either version using the struct hack:

```
type contained
    x::Cint
    y::Cint
    z::Cint
end
type mystruct
    n::Cint
    arr::Ptr{contained}
end
```

If I call a C function from Julia which returns a `Ptr{mystruct}` and save it as `ms`, I can put `m = unsafe_load(ms)` and see `m.n` and the pointer `m.arr`, but I can only check its values with `unsafe_load(m.arr)` in the original case.  Otherwise `unsafe_load(m.arr)` causes a segfault.  What is the right way in Julia to handle C structs containing variable length arrays defined in this fashion?  I would use only the original definition of `mystruct` with `contained *arr` since it works as expected, but I need code that works for the other cases too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [C interface section of the Julia manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#struct-type-correspondences), regarding inline type/struct members:

> Arrays of unknown size are not supported.

However, it is possible to use the address of the struct to figure out the offset to the array data (just like in C), and then access that data using [unsafe_wrap](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/c/#Base.unsafe_wrap).

---

Here is a complete example:

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} contained;

typedef struct {
    int n;
    contained arr[];
} mystruct;

mystruct *return_mystruct() {
    mystruct* ms = malloc(sizeof(mystruct) + 6*sizeof(contained));

    ms->n = 6;

    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        ms->arr[i].x = i+1;
        ms->arr[i].y = i+1;
        ms->arr[i].z = i+1;
    };

    return ms;
}
```

compile with: `gcc -shared -o test test.c`

julia:

```
immutable contained
  x::Cint
  y::Cint
  z::Cint
end
immutable mystruct
  n::Cint
end

ms = ccall((:return_mystruct, "test"), Ptr{mystruct}, ())

n = unsafe_load(ms).n
addr = reinterpret(Ptr{contained}, ms+sizeof(mystruct))
arr = unsafe_wrap(Vector{contained}, addr, n)
```

Notes:

- `type` -> `immutable` in order to ensure that the layout is C compatible (see manual)
- note that the address **must be valid** for the lifetime of any Julia reference to the memory, which generally means it must be heap-allocated)

Comment: What you described as resulting in a segfault is actually the case where it does _not_ segfault.  The following code works and gives the expected output when the C struct is defined with `contained* arr`, but segfaults with `contained arr[1]` or `contained arr[]`:  

`ms = ccall(:mkmystruct, Ptr{mystruct}, ...)`;  

`m = unsafe_load(ms)`;  

`n = m.n`;  

`arr = [unsafe_load(m.arr,i) for i in 1:n]`;  

However, both `arr = unsafe_wrap(Array, m.arr, m.n)` and `arr = unsafe_wrap(Array, ms + sizeof(Cint), m.n)` result in segfaults.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the complete example.  Here `mystruct` doesn't possess `arr` as far as Julia is concerned.  Is there any guarantee that the memory `arr` lives in won't be overwritten by something else until it is  `free`d in another `ccall`?

Comment: See the documentation for `unsafe_wrap`: there is an optional `own` parameter which will tell Julia to `free` the memory when the reference is garbage collected. By default, `own=false`, so Julia won't touch the memory (aside from any assignments made to the `unsafe_wrap`'d array ref). Using `own=true` is advanced usage -- and should never be done in this situation because the first four bytes of the struct will leak. All other guarantees are your responsibility, just as in C. The "struct hack" is somewhat advanced, so use with caution.